# How to compute this form factor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, mathematics

I would really appreciate if someone could help me about computing the form factor $$F(q^2)=\int_0^{\infty}\rho(r)e^{-iq\cdot r}d^3r \quad, $$ when $$\rho (r)=\begin{cases}\rho_0& r<R\\0& r>R\end{cases}\quad . $$ The answer is $$F(q^2)=\frac{3(\sin (qr)-qr\cos(qr))}{(qr)^3},$$
where $r=|\overset{\to}{r}|$, $q=|\overset{\to}{q}|$, $\overset{\to}{q}$, and $\overset{\to}{r}$ are three dimensional vectors, but I don't know how to obtain it. Thanks in advance.

What I've tried: Using spherical coordinates, we have $d^3 r=dxdydz=r^2dr\sin \theta d\theta d\phi$, where $0\leq r\leq R$, $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$, and $0\leq \phi \leq 2\pi$. Then $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-i\overset{\to}{q}\cdot \overset{\to}{r}}d^3 r=\int\int\int e^{-irq\cos\theta}r^2dr\sin \theta d\theta d\phi$$ $$=2\pi \int\int e^{-irq\cos\theta}r^2dr\sin \theta d\theta .$$  Now how can I compute the last integral?

Comment: Transform to spherical coordinates, picking up a $|r|^2\sin{\theta}$ Jacobian factor and a cosine in the exponential from the definition of the inner product, with integration range $0<|r|<R$, $0<\theta<\pi$, and $0<\phi<2\pi$. The resultant integrals are known.

Comment: @QuantumFieldMedalist Thanks very much for the hint. Based on your comment, I've just added my try. I'd appreciate if you could help me about computing the last integral.

Comment: The integral over $\theta$ can be computed by a trig-substitution, namely $x:= \cos \theta$, yielding $2 \frac{\sin{qr}}{q r}$. The remaining $r$ integral may be computed by integration by parts.

Comment: @QuantumFieldMedalist As you said, $\int e^{-irq\cos\theta}\sin \theta d\theta=2\frac{\sin qr}{qr}$. But the remaining $r$ integral is $\rho_0 2\pi (\frac{2}{q})(-\frac{r}{q}\cos qr+\frac{1}{q^2}\sin qr)$ which is different from the answer. Can you help me about this?

Comment: After plugging in your $\theta$ integral, there is still a factor of $r^2$. Thus, the remaining integral is basically $\int_{0}^{R} dr \frac{r}{q} \sin{ q r} = \frac{(\sin{qr} - q R \cos{qr})}{q^{3}}$. Using the fact that $\rho_{0} = \frac{3}{4 \pi R^{3}}$ gives the right answer.

Comment: @QuantumFieldMedalist Got it, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact
$$
\int e^{-iqr \cos\theta} \sin \theta d\theta = -\int e^{-iqr c}  dc
$$
where $c$ is the integration variable that replaced $\cos\theta$. The integral is now elementary. The form factors for spheres (this case), rods and slabs are reported in, e.g., [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.11817) (see equation 42). For more details, see also [Scattering from homogeneous objects](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/740964/226902) and [this answer](https://%20https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/368866/226902).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the nice comments.